# Question about notations

Tags: real-analysis, limits, notation

I am confused. Please, could you help me with this notation $$\exists x_{\delta, \varepsilon}$$
And if possible with some example.

Comment: Maybe just means that that object depends on $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$, that is, those subscripts are "tags".

Comment: $\liminf _{x \rightarrow p} f(x)=A$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0 \exists \delta>0$ such that
$f(x) \geqslant A-\varepsilon$ provided $x \in S_{p, \delta}, \forall \delta>0 \exists x_{\delta, \varepsilon} \in S_{p, \delta}$ such that $f\left(x_{\delta, \varepsilon}\right) \leqslant A+\varepsilon$

Comment: @TuralSukurov That's very important. If you could add that to the question post above it would be very useful, since it's the place where the notation is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a proposition like
$$(\forall a ) \;(\exists B) \;: ...$$
it means that for each $ a$, there exists some $ B $ which depends on $ a $. So, we should write $ \exists B_a $ to show that $ B $ depends on $ a$.

If you have
$$(\forall \delta ) \; (\forall \epsilon )\; (\exists x) \;:...$$
this means that $ x $ depends on both $ \epsilon $ and $ \delta $. we should write $ \exists x_{\delta,\epsilon}$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdullah thanks I understood